# maximizing the inverse degree in a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, trees, algebraic-graph-theory

The inverse degree in the graph $G$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
r(G) = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{d_i},
\end{align*}
where $d_i$ is the degree of node (vertex) $i$. Is the connected graph with maximum $r(G)$ always of a diameter $1$ or $2$ for any fixed number of links (edges) $L \in [N-1, \binom{N}{2}]$?

Comment: I know "a way" for going towards the maximum, by doing the change for two degrees $(a,b)$ into $(a+1,b-1)$, if $n - 1 > a \ge b > 1$, because $\frac{1}{a}+ \frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{a+1} + \frac{1}{b-1}$, but there is no much insight for the diameter, although intuitively seems to be $2$ for $L<\binom{N}{2}$ and $1$ for $L=\binom{N}{2}$.

Comment: @Fabien No, a star is better. With four vertices, for example, a path $P_4$ will have degrees $1, 2, 2, 1$, so $r(P_4) = 3$, but a star $K_{1,3}$ will have degrees $1, 1, 1, 3$, so $r(K_{1,3}) = 3\frac{1}{3} > 3$. For $n$ vertices, $r(P_n) = 2 + (n-2)/2 = 1 + n/2$, and $r(K_{1, n - 1} = (n - 1) + 1/(n-1) > 1 + n/2$ for $n \ge 4$.

Comment: @simco Basically you have the non-linear programming problem
$$\text{Maximize}\ r(G) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \dfrac{1}{d_i}\\
\text{subject to}\ \sum_{i = 1}^{N} d_i = 2L\\
d_i \ge 1,\ i = 1, \ldots, N$$
You might be able to do this using dynamic programming.

Comment: @simco I don't really recommend that approach, though. You're better off using graph theoretic arguments.

Comment: @M. Vinay: Yes, the non-linear programming does not care for the connectivity and whether $d_i$ can make a graph.

Comment: @simco True, but earlier, you hadn't specified connectivity in your question ($L \ge N - 1$ does not ensure connectivity - consider the union of a tree and a cycle). However, I suspect it'll still give you a valid answer.